# Extract particular layers from DXF file and make shapefile

Tags: ogr2ogr, dxf

I've been given a DXF file with many different points, linestrings and polygons. Alongside these, there are some text annotations with arrows pointing to a particular feature. (The CAD-user's annotation of the area).

I'm using `ogr2ogr` to convert each layer as a shapefile like so:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" C:/test/DXF_line.shp C:/test/Original_DXF.dxf -nlt Linestring  -s_srs EPSG:29902 -t_srs EPSG:29902 -skipfailures
```

However, I'm wondering is there a way to split the annotations from the points, etc? As they currently seem to be converted to a point feature making it hard to distinguish between actual features and points which are just notes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate the data in this way:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -skipfailure  --config DXF_MERGE_BLOCK_GEOMETRIES TRUE --config DXF_INLINE_BLOCKS TRUE -nlt POINT      -sql "select *, ogr_style from entities where OGR_GEOMETRY LIKE '%POINT%'"         C:/test/annotations.shp C:/test/Original_DXF.DXF
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -skipfailure  --config DXF_MERGE_BLOCK_GEOMETRIES TRUE --config DXF_INLINE_BLOCKS TRUE -nlt LINESTRING -sql "select *, ogr_style from entities where OGR_GEOMETRY LIKE '%LINE%'"          C:/test/line.shp C:/test/Original_DXF.DXF
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -skipfailure  --config DXF_MERGE_BLOCK_GEOMETRIES TRUE --config DXF_INLINE_BLOCKS TRUE -nlt POLYGON    -sql "select *, ogr_style from entities where OGR_GEOMETRY LIKE '%POLYGON%'"       C:/test/polygon.shp C:/test/Original_DXF.DXF 
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -skipfailure  --config DXF_MERGE_BLOCK_GEOMETRIES TRUE --config DXF_INLINE_BLOCKS TRUE -nlt POINT      -sql "select *, ogr_style from entities where OGR_GEOMETRY = 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION'" C:/test/symbolpoint.shp C:/test/Original_DXF.DXF
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -skipfailure  --config DXF_MERGE_BLOCK_GEOMETRIES TRUE --config DXF_INLINE_BLOCKS TRUE -nlt LINESTRING -sql "select *, ogr_style from entities where OGR_GEOMETRY = 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION'" C:/test/symbollinestring.shp C:/test/Original_DXF.DXF
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -skipfailure  --config DXF_MERGE_BLOCK_GEOMETRIES TRUE --config DXF_INLINE_BLOCKS TRUE -nlt POLYGON    -sql "select *, ogr_style from entities where OGR_GEOMETRY = 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION'" C:/test/symbolpolygon.shp C:/test/Original_DXF.DXF
```